# Rigging live worms - Tzaar Baalei Chayim?

Tags: halacha, fish, tzaar-baalei-chayyim, bugs

Is there any halachic objection to rigging a live worm onto a hook when fishing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem not from Trumas haDeshen P/K [105](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14655&st=&pgnum=174).  The case in the end where he brings achzarius seems to be talking in a case where there were tamer options.  Dead worms just won't catch fish.  Although if your going for lake trout, mini-marshmallows work great!

Comment: Thanks for the mareh makom (and the marshmallow advice). I actually got the opposite impression from his ending -- he seems to be saying that common practice is to avoid any kind of cruelty, even in cases where it is 100% permissible, so as not to be punished with yissurim.

Comment: I thought that was referring to the plucking alive case since you can do it after the animal is dead.  Otherwise, we shouldn't be packing animals.

Comment: What do mean by "packing animals"?

Comment: My lazy way of saying loading pack animals.  That was one of the proofs brought that you don't say tzaar b.c. if it's for human purpose.

Comment: I don't know if loading an animal would be considered "achzarius/cruelty." The animal may be working hard, but it is not experiencing severe trauma, as an impaled worm presumably does.

Comment: The end of the Trumas haDeshen quotes from piskei R"Y who writes that there is no issur of TBC unless "ain lo revach"- there's no significant gain.  The Trumas haDeshen then conludes "v'haynu kdleil".  So the chiluk seems to be- what significant benefit do you get.  Whatever the benefit of plucking the foul alive is probably insignificant- do it when it's dead.  Making animals look nicer/"talk" also does not bring the person significant benefit.  That's the way I learned it.

Comment: I think a concern would be what  Beb MOshe said is the problem with Tzar of an animal the human being desensitized  see here:http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1929/tzar-balay-chaim-killing-flies

Comment: Granted it is a concern.  So we minimize as much as possible.  Though it is not taken to the extent that we become vegetarians because of the shochet's middos.  Here's some food for thought ;) When you catch a fish, how do you proceed?  Should you let it suffocate, leading to a terrible death.  Or should you knock it out b'yadayim?  Both would be mutar, but the concern would be building achzarius.

Comment: @Dave "but it is not experiencing severe trauma, as an impaled worm presumably does" - worms can not feel pain, they do not have the nerves or brain for it. They are able to detect noxious stimuli (and try to avoid it), but to go from there to pain is a stretch. A simple test can be done with an ant: Cut off the leg of an ant, then let it go - it will continue walking like normal, with no indication anything is wrong. A mammal will never do this. Worms are even less developed than ants.